# Reference `title` from another table `title`

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the table `_primary` with UNIQUE `title` and i have the table `_secondary` where i need set reference `title` for `_primary` table.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand this question. What problem are you having doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution and let me know its working for you.

```
ALTER TABLE _secondary
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_title
FOREIGN KEY (title) REFERENCES _primary(title)
```